# A Definite Integral under Absolute Value

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate the following
$$
\left|\operatorname{sgn}(a)\cdot\int_{-\frac{\sqrt{4ac-2}}{2a}}^{\frac{\sqrt{4ac-2}}{2a}}\left(c-\operatorname{sgn}(a)\sqrt{\frac{4ac-1}{4a^2}-x^2}-ax^2\right)dx\right|
$$
where $a$ and $c$ are real numbers but $ac\geqslant\frac{1}{2}$. I am sorry that the integral is so full of variables. I tried this on my own and my answer came to be the following$$
 \left|\frac{c\sqrt{4ac-2}}{a}-\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(a)\left(\sqrt{4ac-2}+(4ac-1)\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{4ac-2}\right))}{4a^2}-\frac{(2ac-1)\sqrt{4ac-2}}{6a^2}\right|
$$
But, due to the nature of the problem from which, the question was generated, the question should not change its value if all the $a$s and $c$s are replaced by their negatives, which does not happen in my solution due to the extra $\operatorname{sgn}(a)$ in the second term. Please guide me. Also, the value from $\tan^{-1}$ is its principal value in radians and $\sqrt{}$ is the principal square root.